# Store the value of a sql query and use the result in another sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display an attendance sheet where the headers will be the date which will be from database and it will have duplicate dates for which i will use " select DISTINCT from "abc".
And the name of employees will also come from database.

How can i store the value of dates so that i can use it in another sql query..?

In the next query the value of date and the name should match and it can display the result whether the employee was present or absent.??

I have tried everything i know but no solution..

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez

<?php 
       $results=$mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM attendance_date ORDER BY id DESC");
       if($results)
       {
       while($obj=$results->fetch_object())
       {
       echo $obj->name ;
       
       }
       }
       ?>


And in the next query
i need the values of $results in the sql query i.e.

Comment: My next sql is:
$aa=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM attendance_sheet where date = ??  ");

should i use this
    $aa=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM attendance_sheet where date = $results  ");

SORRY I AM CONFUSED

Comment: several as in there would be different dates

Comment: i want every date to be displayed and according to that i need to check whether the employee was present or not..

Comment: can a loop be applied to the date??

Comment: yes how can it be applied in this case?? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one loop for the main results and an inner loop to get results based on the main results :

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM attendance_date ORDER BY id DESC");
if ( $results )
   { while ( $obj = $results->fetch_object() )  // ◄■■ MAIN LOOP.
     { echo $obj->name;                                                       ▼
       $aa = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM attendance_sheet where date='{$obj->date}'");
       while ( $obj2 = $aa->fetch_object() )  // ◄■■ SECONDARY LOOP.
       { // DO SOMETHING HERE.
       }
     } 
   }
```

Notice how `$obj->date` is used in the secondary query.

Comment: its done... minor issue of mine... Sorry.. 
Thanks for the help man.
Really really thanks..!!!